# Javascript, CSS & HTML: How to swap images using onclick etc.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have the below code in JS, HTML,CSS, which currently look like this.
(https://jsfiddle.net/sidsingh29/591hfwLd/33/)

Project has 2 objects, there locations are:

1. Red Circle: https://drexel.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_ezDZcerD82eHf81
2. Green Circle: https://drexel.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_3XmJ5y3lOBQD469

What I want:

1. Everytime the circle is clicked the 2 objects should alternate between each other. Eg. Red Circle --> Click ---> Green Circle. .... (R,G,G,G,R,R,G.....)
2. The movement of the circle should always be random, anywhere on the dimensions of the given dialog box. It's basically like a game and the ball should alternate colors and move around every time you click on it. The two colors are basically the two objects(images) that I wanna use.
3. Code has to be in these languages HTML, CSS, JS

*****code*****

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
        var docHeight = $(document).height(),
            docWidth = $(document).width(),
            $div = $('#test'),
            divWidth = $div.width(),
            divHeight = $div.height(),
            heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
            widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
        
        $div.css({
            left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
            top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
        });
    });
```

```css
#test {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:70px;
        background-color:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><img id = "item" src="https://drexel.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_ezDZcerD82eHf81" style="width: 51px; height: 51px;"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the edit. Were you able to find a solution for my problem as well?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toggleImage = () => {
    const images = [
        "https://drexel.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_ezDZcerD82eHf81",
        "https://drexel.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_3XmJ5y3lOBQD469"
    ];
    let image = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? images[0] : images[1];
    $("#test #item").attr("src", image);
};

$('#test').click(function() {
        var docHeight = $(document).height(),
            docWidth = $(document).width(),
            $div = $('#test'),
            divWidth = $div.width(),
            divHeight = $div.height(),
            heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
            widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
        
        $div.css({
            left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
            top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
        });
        toggleImage();
    });
```

```css
#test {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:70px;
        background-color:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><img id = "item" src="https://drexel.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_ezDZcerD82eHf81" style="width: 51px; height: 51px;"></div>
```